# Want to create search field but error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django

I am doing a django project, a music app .It contains artist name,album title,genre and image. When I create a search form ,I get this error.I am using django version 1.9.1

view.py

```
from django.views import generic
from . models import Album
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView , UpdateView ,DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm
from django.db.models import Q

def get_queryset(self):
    query= self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        return Album.objects.filter(Q(album_title__icontains=query))
    else:
        return Album.objects.all()
```

form.py

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left"  method="GET" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >search</button>
</form>
```

url.py

```
#checking for search
url(r'^search/$', views.get_queryset, name='search'),
```

Image of error in browser: 
 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_queryset` is not a `View` class, so the `self` argument is actually the request object.

To correct your problem you can simply do:

```
def get_queryset(request):
    query= request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        return Album.objects.filter(album_title__icontains=query)
    else:
        return Album.objects.all()
```

but I suggest to double check the docs about the [`views`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/) and the [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: thank you...but i want to my search form to work in the way that when i provide it's album_title info then it shows at first.so for that should i need to create new form or it can work on the same page.please provide me detail.My project look this : https://ibb.co/nr83rk ,https://ibb.co/kzG1cQ